# What is Windows Update really doing on my disk?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Can someone shed light on what Windows Update really does (beside updating windows, of course)?

After all updates are downloaded (forget about "slow connection" and similar crap) WU starts trashing on disk for HOURS (sometime DAYS).
It is time enough to rewrite each single bit, even the "unused" ones, several times over.

Now I am trying to install latest release (20H2) since ~30 hours and it is still trashing, preparing, restarting, ...

Is this considered "normal"?

If so I'm really curious to understand what's REALLY doing (beside stress-testing my disk).

Update:

Specs of my PC are (I am sorry all screen captures are in Italian, but I hope whoever is really able to answer my question will "just need the numbers" knowing quite well how to fill-in-the blanks; I *could* translate, if that's deemed useful, but I risk to confuse things even further because my translation won't, of course, match "original US-English" wording):

```
Processore  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz   3.70 GHz
RAM installata  32,0 GB
Tipo sistema    Sistema operativo a 64 bit, processore basato su x64
Penna e tocco   Nessun input penna o tocco disponibile per questo schermo

Dischi:

Descrizione Unità disco
Produttore  (unità disco standard)
Modello CT1000MX500SSD4
Byte/Settore    512
Supporto caricato   Sì
Tipo supporto   Disco rigido fisso
Partizioni  3
Bus SCSI    0
Unità logica SCSI   0
Porta SCSI  0
ID destinazione SCSI    0
Settori/Traccia 63
Dimensione  931,51 GB (1.000.202.273.280 Byte)
Cilindri totali 121.601
Settori totali  1.953.520.065
Tracce totali   31.008.255
Tracce/Cilindri 255
Partizione  Disco #0, partizione #0
Dimensione partizione   128,00 MB (134.217.728 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 1.048.576 byte
Partizione  Disco #0, partizione #1
Dimensione partizione   3,73 GB (4.000.317.440 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 499.500.711.936 byte
Partizione  Disco #0, partizione #2
Dimensione partizione   143,05 GB (153.599.606.784 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 503.501.029.376 byte
    
Descrizione Unità disco
Produttore  (unità disco standard)
Modello TOSHIBA HDWD130
Byte/Settore    512
Supporto caricato   Sì
Tipo supporto   Disco rigido fisso
Partizioni  2
Bus SCSI    0
Unità logica SCSI   0
Porta SCSI  1
ID destinazione SCSI    0
Settori/Traccia 63
Dimensione  2,73 TB (3.000.590.369.280 Byte)
Cilindri totali 364.801
Settori totali  5.860.528.065
Tracce totali   93.024.255
Tracce/Cilindri 255
Partizione  Disco #2, partizione #0
Dimensione partizione   2,73 TB (3.000.583.061.504 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 1.048.576 byte
Partizione  Disco #2, partizione #1
Dimensione partizione   8,00 MB (8.388.608 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 3.000.584.110.080 byte
    
Descrizione Unità disco
Produttore  (unità disco standard)
Modello TOSHIBA HDWD130
Byte/Settore    512
Supporto caricato   Sì
Tipo supporto   Disco rigido fisso
Partizioni  2
Bus SCSI    3
Unità logica SCSI   0
Porta SCSI  1
ID destinazione SCSI    0
Settori/Traccia 63
Dimensione  2,73 TB (3.000.590.369.280 Byte)
Cilindri totali 364.801
Settori totali  5.860.528.065
Tracce totali   93.024.255
Tracce/Cilindri 255
Partizione  Disco #5, partizione #0
Dimensione partizione   2,73 TB (3.000.583.061.504 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 1.048.576 byte
Partizione  Disco #5, partizione #1
Dimensione partizione   8,00 MB (8.388.608 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 3.000.584.110.080 byte
    
Descrizione Unità disco
Produttore  (unità disco standard)
Modello TOSHIBA HDWD130
Byte/Settore    512
Supporto caricato   Sì
Tipo supporto   Disco rigido fisso
Partizioni  2
Bus SCSI    1
Unità logica SCSI   0
Porta SCSI  1
ID destinazione SCSI    0
Settori/Traccia 63
Dimensione  2,73 TB (3.000.590.369.280 Byte)
Cilindri totali 364.801
Settori totali  5.860.528.065
Tracce totali   93.024.255
Tracce/Cilindri 255
Partizione  Disco #3, partizione #0
Dimensione partizione   2,73 TB (3.000.583.061.504 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 1.048.576 byte
Partizione  Disco #3, partizione #1
Dimensione partizione   8,00 MB (8.388.608 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 3.000.584.110.080 byte
    
Descrizione Unità disco
Produttore  (unità disco standard)
Modello ST750LM022 HN-M750MBB
Byte/Settore    512
Supporto caricato   Sì
Tipo supporto   Disco rigido fisso
Partizioni  3
Bus SCSI    2
Unità logica SCSI   0
Porta SCSI  0
ID destinazione SCSI    0
Settori/Traccia 63
Dimensione  698,64 GB (750.153.761.280 Byte)
Cilindri totali 91.201
Settori totali  1.465.144.065
Tracce totali   23.256.255
Tracce/Cilindri 255
Partizione  Disco #1, partizione #0
Dimensione partizione   499,00 MB (523.239.424 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 1.048.576 byte
Partizione  Disco #1, partizione #1
Dimensione partizione   100,00 MB (104.857.600 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 524.288.000 byte
Partizione  Disco #1, partizione #2
Dimensione partizione   698,03 GB (749.508.493.312 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 645.922.816 byte
    
Descrizione Unità disco
Produttore  (unità disco standard)
Modello TOSHIBA HDWD130
Byte/Settore    512
Supporto caricato   Sì
Tipo supporto   Disco rigido fisso
Partizioni  2
Bus SCSI    2
Unità logica SCSI   0
Porta SCSI  1
ID destinazione SCSI    0
Settori/Traccia 63
Dimensione  2,73 TB (3.000.590.369.280 Byte)
Cilindri totali 364.801
Settori totali  5.860.528.065
Tracce totali   93.024.255
Tracce/Cilindri 255
Partizione  Disco #4, partizione #0
Dimensione partizione   2,73 TB (3.000.583.061.504 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 1.048.576 byte
Partizione  Disco #4, partizione #1
Dimensione partizione   8,00 MB (8.388.608 Byte)
Offset avvio partizione 3.000.584.110.080 byte
```

Which doesn't seem particularly "low end" to me.

I do repeat the question:

Win 10 is using 134GB on a single partition (Partizione Disco #1, partizione #2), including two large games I hope WU won't touch.

The trashing time is enough to rewrite ALL this TENS of times.

What is Windows Update really doing?

Reading the whole disk to write one byte, rinse and repeat?

I really do not understand.

Saying I need a faster PC is really neither useful nor understandable.

Update2:

Apparently my update finished Ok:
[image]

... but WU is still "not satisfied":
[image]

What's happening?
Should I keep updating?

Comment: If you update from an older release from before 2020 releases like 20H1 20H2 (there is no 20H4) are not updates they are upgrades. Which means that the whole Windows OS is replaced by a new version. If this operation takes a long time then most likely your PC is a bit older and your HDD is very slow. Modern PCs use SSDs are finish this upgrade in about an hour or less.

Comment: Sounds like you need a SSD. ;-)

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for the fast answer; I updated OP with my PC specs. I do understand the difference between update and upgrade (actual target was 20H2, my bad) and I try to keep it completely up-to-date (I'm pretty sure I manually ran WU several times in 2020, besides the automatic runs). I still don't understand what's really happening; times are NOT compatible with a "simple rewrite", even a complete one.

Comment: @DanielB: I do have one (but Win10 is on a rotating spindle), please see specs in updated OP. As said a "non optimal" partitioning does not fully explain such long disk trashing (IMHO, of course). I would like to understand what WU is really doing.

Comment: If the Windows PC operative while it is installing the update? Can you e.g. start other applications or does the PC totally block?

Comment: @Robert: It depends on what you exactly mean by that. PC is working (slow) while "preparing" and "downloading" (which already takes long enough), then it asks for reboot and I get a nice blue screen with a rotating icon. In that phase PC is obviously not available to do anything. It is THIS phase (actually split in several "shutting down", "power up", etc. etc sub-phases) taking hours with disk led almost completely fixed "on" I am concerned about.

Comment: @ZioByte - You should work on the clarity of your question by editing it. Specifically the non-English text

Comment: @Ramhound: I can do it, but I don't understand what I should "clarify": WU is trashing on disk for a time that, on my hardware, should be enough to rewrite the whole disk (at least) 10 times. Is there anyone who knows what is it doing and why takes so long? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: " WU starts trashing on disk for HOURS (sometime DAYS)"  That is just an incredibly slow drive, possibly too full. Windows Insider does a complete rewrite and it takes 3 or 4 hours on a 7,200 rpm drive. if there was a full rewrite on my SSD laptop, it took about an hour. On a decent drive, Windows Update rewrites are not a big issue.

Comment: You indicated you meant 20H2 not 20H4 and you have a bunch of text most users cannot read describing the meat and potatoes of your question.  I could probably figure it out with the Windows Update log, but that won’t be in English, so I won’t ask for it.

Comment: @John: I added specs. As said that explanation does *not* seem to be compatible.

Comment: Whenever I see WU thrashing like that, it is always a disk issue.